# Flutter: track number of times the application opened

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way a way to track flutter application is opened or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh, so basically. I was so stupid asking this.
It is an easy problem by using the database, either the SQLite, or query from server.

- retrieve the data from database (tracking column)
- increment that by 1
- finally update the database.